# Non-greedy capture groups in Postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I'm trying to implement a regex expression to parse out different groups of a string. The string I am provided signals a customer who wants to change their primary language on our platform from X to Y, so it will look like

- `language_change__from_english_to_spanish`
- `language_change__from_spanish_to_somali`
- `language_change__from_simplified_chinese_to_english`

I have a regex to parse out the languages (the original language, and then the new language):

`SUBSTRING(language_field FROM '^language_change__([a-zA-Z_]+)_to_[a-zA-Z_]+$')`

The works great for the original language, but it does not work as well for the new language, because sometimes people have entered in `language_change__from_english_to_spanish_`. So what is actually parsed is `spanish_` instead of `spanish`.

I know that I could easily just wrap my `SUBSTRING(...)` with a `REPLACE` to replace the final `_`, but I'm trying to find a way to do it using regex to sharpen my regex skills. I basically want to ignore the final `_`. However, I cannot remove `_` from my capture group, because some languages coded in our system have `_`: `simplified_chinese`, for instance.

Basically, I want my capture group to include the first `_` followed by text (like `simplified_chinese`), but do not include the `_` if it is at the end of the string (`english_`).

**So when `language_change__from_spanish_to_english_` is entered, I should still capture `english`, and not `english_` as the language.**

I tried various ways:

- Using **negative lookahead**: `SUBSTRING(language_field FROM '^language_change__[a-zA-Z_]+_to_([a-zA-Z_]+)(?!_)$')`
- Using **non-greedy capture groups**: `SUBSTRING(language_field FROM '^language_change__[a-zA-Z_]+_to_([a-zA-Z_]+?)$')`
- Using a **combination of negative lookahead and non-greedy capture groups**: `SUBSTRING(language_field FROM '^language_change__[a-zA-Z_]+_to_([a-zA-Z_]+?)(?!_)$')`

I feel like I've been on StackOverflow long enough to not say "nothing works", but all three things I tried above still yield `english_` and not `english` when people incorrectly have entered `language_change__from_spanish_to_english_` on our end.

Can someone give me some pointers what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
SUBSTRING(language_field FROM '^language_change__[a-zA-Z_]+_to_([a-zA-Z_]+?)_*$')
```

The `([a-zA-Z_]+?)_*$` part means:

- `([a-zA-Z_]+?)` - Group 1: match 1 or more ASCII letters or `_` as few times as possible
- `_*` - match 0 or more `_` chars
- `$` - at the end of string.

The `([a-zA-Z_]+?)` pattern will match 1 char, then `_*$` pattern part will be tried. If `_*$` fails to match, the engine will backtrack and the `([a-zA-Z_]+?)` pattern will grab another char and the tests will repeat. Hence, if `_`s exist at the end of the string, they will not be included in the capturing group, they will be matched with `_*` part, and will thus be discarded from the result.

See [this regex debugger step by step](https://regex101.com/r/jIbIla/1/debugger) to see the regex in action.

Comment: This works! Wow, thank you. Just so I can learn, could you explain really briefly how you approached solving this so I can use your same thought process in the future? Ie. I know you explained what each part means, but how did you know this problem required using `_*`, for instance?

Comment: I'll accept the answer in in 10 minutes (when SO lets me)